# Number to letter swapping in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a vector, for example, `V = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`. Is there a way to change this to the letters, `[ a,b,c,d ]`?

Answer (score 11):

Using 'a' directly instead of ascii codes might be slightly more readable

```
charString = char(V-1+'a');
```

Uppercase is then obtained with

```
charString = char(V-1+'A');
```

Comment: blast!  i figured this would work, but didn't have a copy of matlab handy to make sure.  good show :)

Comment: Wow, I've been wanting something like this for ever. Now that I see it I feel stupid for not figuring it out sooner. Thank you and well done. Now if only Excel weren't terribad, I wouldn't need this ugly (but brilliant) hack!

Answer (score 4):

There are two simple ways to do this. One way is a simple index.

```
C = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
V = [8 5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12 4];

C(V)
ans =
helloworld
```

Of course, char will do it too. The char answer is better because it does not require you to store a list of letters to index into.

```
char('a' + V - 1)
ans =
helloworld
```

This is best since when you add 'a' to something, it converts 'a' to its ascii representation on the fly. +'a' will yield 97, the ascii form of 'a'.

A nice thing is it also works for 'A', so if you wanted caps, just add 'A' instead.

```
char('A' + V - 1)
ans =
HELLOWORLD
```

You can find more information about working with strings in MATLAB from these commands:

```
help strings
doc strings
```

Comment: char() is also prefereable in the case that the order of the letters changes at some point in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
C = char(V+ones(size(V)).*(97-1))
```

should work (97 is the ASCII code for 'a', and you want 1 to map to 'a' it looks like).

Comment: In all of these comments and solutions (not to just pick on yours, Matt), I would probably write the code so that 'a' appeared in the code; for example, I would write yours as... C = char(V+ones(size(V)).*(double('a')-1));  I think that that makes the PURPOSE of the code a bit more obvious to the "casual" reader, even if he DOES know that ASCII a == 97.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [CHAR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/char.html) function, which turns a number (i.e. ASCII code) into a character:

```
charString = char(V+96);
```

**EDIT:** To go backwards (mapping 'a' to 1, 'b' to 2, etc.), use the [DOUBLE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/double.html) function to recast the character back to its ASCII code number:

```
V = double(charString)-96;
```

Comment: could you tell me how to do the reverse?